# Making a Div fixed on Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make a div fixed on detection of Scrolling by the Users. 
Example: Right Sidebar of Facebook, it gets stuck when a certain scroll position is attained.

Comment: I've used this before take a look http://blog.echoenduring.com/2010/11/15/freebie-contained-sticky-scroll-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 8):

`position:fixed` is the answer.
But you can always look at a website's source if you want to know how they do something. Very educational!

Answer (score 5):

Monitor whether or not we're scrolling.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
  //we're scrolling our position is greater than 0 from the top of the page.
  $("#element").css({'position' : 'fixed'});
}
```

***EDIT**

*Do it without jQuery..*

```
if(window.scrollTop() > 0){
  document.getElementById('element').style.position="fixed";
}
```

Comment: scrollTop is not jQuery specific, but the rest of it is.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean?

But you can add the CSS-propery position: fixed; to it to make it appear on the sam place even after scrolling.

[More on CSS positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It seams you are looking for `position: sticky;`.

Learn more: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/